# What could be the reason for Kotlin Result class being not properly injected in Guice?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, dependency-injection, guice

This is just an example but hopefully illustrates the problem. All seem to be related to the Kotlin Result class. For other generic classes like e.g. java Optional or self-made Kotlin generic class, all work as expected and both implementations in the given example are injected properly.

Binding configuration looks like this:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.Singleton
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral

class BillingModule : AbstractModule() {

    override fun configure() {
        bind(object :
            TypeLiteral<CardProcessor<Result<String>>>() {}).toProvider(CreditCardProcessorProvider::class.java)
            .`in`(Singleton::class.java)

        bind(object : TypeLiteral<CardProcessor<Result<Int>>>() {}).toProvider(DebitCardProcessorProvider::class.java)
            .`in`(Singleton::class.java)
    }

}
```

Guice card providers:

```
import com.google.inject.Provider

class CreditCardProcessorProvider : Provider<CardProcessor<Result<String>>> {

    private val creditCardProcessor = CreditCardProcessor<Result<String>>()

    override fun get(): CardProcessor<Result<String>> {
        return creditCardProcessor
    }

}
```

```
import com.google.inject.Provider

class DebitCardProcessorProvider : Provider<CardProcessor<Result<Int>>> {

    private val debitCardProcessor = DebitCardProcessor<Result<Int>>()

    override fun get(): CardProcessor<Result<Int>> {
        return debitCardProcessor
    }

}
```

and the service with constructor injection:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

class RealBillingService @Inject constructor(
    private val creditCardProcessor: CardProcessor<Result<String>>,
    private val debitCardProcessor: CardProcessor<Result<Int>>,
) {

    fun chargeOrder() {
        val creditCardOutput = creditCardProcessor.charge(Result.success("ok"))
        val debitCardOutput = debitCardProcessor.charge(Result.success(1))
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, this configuration results in the following exception:

```
1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for CardProcessor<kotlin.Result<Integer>> was bound.

Requested by:
1  : RealBillingService.<init>(RealBillingService.kt:3)
      \_ for 2nd parameter
     while locating RealBillingService

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION

2) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for CardProcessor<kotlin.Result<String>> was bound.

Requested by:
1  : RealBillingService.<init>(RealBillingService.kt:3)
      \_ for 1st parameter
     while locating RealBillingService
```

What is also interesting is that the given configuration, when accessing a concrete implementation of a card processor manually, returns the expected value correctly. Wondering how this could be fixed on constructor injection? From my side already tried with [named bindings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guice/guice_named_binding.htm) and [binding annotations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guice/guice_binding_annotations.htm) but without luck.

```
    var creditCardProcessor =
        injector.getInstance(Key.get(object : TypeLiteral<CardProcessor<Result<String>>>() {}))
```

Kotlin version: 1.7.10
Guice version: com.google.inject:guice:5.1.0